# Generating dynamic pretty urls via .htaccess file

Tags: regex, .htaccess, friendly-url

I'm attempting to generate dynamic 'pretty URLs' via .htaccess so that `http://mysite.com/episode.php?episode=1` will become `http://mysite.com/1`, however obviously I want this to be applicable to all episode numbers between a potential range of 1 - 999. I have the following, however I'm getting a 503 error thrown when I load up my .htaccess file:

```
Options -Multiviews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^mysite\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://mysite.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^/episode/\(\?:0|\[1-9\]\\d{0,2}\)$ //episode.php?episode=(?:0|[1-9]\d{0,2}) [L]
```

I can't seem to work out where I'm going wrong and not really understanding why a 503 is being thrown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^episode/(0|[1-9]\d{0,2})$ /episode.php?episode=$1 [L,QSA]
```

More information about `QSA`: [apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa)

Comment: Thanks for your response. Have I got this the wrong way round? I want `http://mysite.com/episode.php?episode=1` to become `http://mysite.com/1` rather than the other way round. When I load as you've formatted above, and as I did previous, it looks like it's trying to change the other way round. Am I missing something?

Comment: You are looking at it from the wrong direction. When a user navigates to `http://mysite.com/1`, the server will serve her `http://mysite.com/episode.php?episode=1` instead. The URL the user sees will still be `http://mysite.com/1`.

Comment: Okay, now I understand. That still doesn't appear to be happening though. If a user navigates to `http://mysite.com/1` I'm getting a 404 error thrown.

Comment: Yea, I thought of that already and I get the same 404 thrown. I'm completely baffled to be honest!

Comment: It seems RewriteRule doesn't like the leading slash. I removed it.